# Eclipse JDT Field Declaration

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to check if a class object creation is after all the declaration or not?
example

```
private final int x;
private static final Myclass c = new Myclass();
private static final int deposit = 100;
```

I want to check and print if any declaration is there after `private static final Myclass c = new Myclass();` (Yes here `private static final int deposit = 100;` is present). I am using eclipse JDT.

How to check a given FieldDeclaration node is last one or not?

This is my current work

```
public boolean visit(FieldDeclaration node) {

    Type t=node.getType();
    if(t.toString().equals("Myclass"))
    {

        System.out.println("Class declaration found");
    }

    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent of that `FieldDeclaration` node, which have to a `TypeDeclaration`. That node has the method `getFields()` providing an array of all field declarations.

```
public boolean visit(FieldDeclaration node) {
    if (node.getParent().getNodeType() == ASTNode.TYPE_DECLARATION) {
        TypeDeclaration parentType = (TypeDeclaration) node.getParent();
        int lastFieldIdx = parentType.getFields().length - 1;
        FieldDeclaration lastFieldInParent = parentType.getFields()[lastFieldIdx];
        boolean isLastFieldDecl = lastFieldInParent.equals(node);
        // ...
    }
    return super.visit(node);
}
```